# How to filter deleted Test Cases (WorkItems) from TFS server?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a C# project with some SQL queries to get data from TFS using API. As we all know, we can't delete a test case / work item from TFS Server permanently. It just removes case from UI, not from database. So how to filter deleted cases from non deleted cases?

I have used below query:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [Team Project]=" + "'" + projname + "'";
```

So this query returns me all the cases present in projname project including deleted cases. Any pointers or help?

Comment: For those hitting "no reserch done button" please reserch yourself and give me a single link that has similar question.I will ask admin to remove this question/post.

Comment: Hi Nakul, how are you "deleting" a Test Case?  Are you just removing it from a Test Suite or setting it to a Closed state? Are you trying to find all the Test Cases in a Test Plan?

Comment: I am just removing from a Test Suite. Really sorry for ambiguioues question. And yes I am trying to find all the cases in a project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `State` column, which will have one of the following values:

- Accepted
- Active
- Approved
- Closed
- Committed
- Design
- Done
- In Progress
- New
- Open
- Ready
- **Removed**
- Requested
- Resolved
- To Do

The following `where` clause should do it:

```
where [State] != 'Removed'
```

Or

```
where [State] <> 'Removed'
```

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your answer. But the test case doesn't have State as 'Removed'. In MTM I use query to find test and found all the cases are in "Design" state including the deleted one.

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing you'll need to join to a different table, I'm no expert on team foundation, but I'll have a poke around and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Hi Mike, I just need table schema so that I can create query by joining tables. Actually couldn't find the schema of all TFS tables any where on net. You have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If you have just removed the Test Case from the Test Suite then the Work Item still exists in a Design or Ready state.  You could consider setting it to Closed if you no longer need it.

Rather than querying the Work Items you should interrogate the Test Plan.

Using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/densto/archive/2010/03/04/the-test-management-api-part-2-creating-modifying-test-plans.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/07/06/tfs-api-part-27-test-plans-test-suites-test-cases-mapping/) as reference, you can list out all your Test Plans, Test Suites and Test Cases depending on what you need.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;

namespace TestInfo
{
    class GetTestData
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serverUrl = "http://tfs2013:8080/tfs/defaultcollection";
            string project = "MyProject";

            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverUrl));
            ITestManagementService tms = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
            ITestManagementTeamProject proj = tms.GetTeamProject(project);

            // List all Test Plans
            foreach (ITestPlan p in proj.TestPlans.Query("Select * From TestPlan"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");

                Console.WriteLine("Test Plan - {0} : {1}", p.Id, p.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");

                foreach (ITestSuiteBase suite in p.RootSuite.SubSuites)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tTest Suite: {0}", suite.Title);

                    IStaticTestSuite staticSuite = suite as IStaticTestSuite;
                    ITestSuiteEntryCollection suiteentrys = suite.TestCases;

                    foreach (ITestSuiteEntry testcase in suiteentrys)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\tTest Case - {0} : {1}", testcase.Id, testcase.Title);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                  }

                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```